# Refresh WebView every (N) seconds

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am searching for a code thru which I can refresh webView every N seconds. I got few of the brilliant answers but since I am pretty new in iOS development I am not able identify where do I need to place the refresh snippet.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var websites = "www.example.com/start/home.asp"



    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self as? WKNavigationDelegate
        view = webView


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://" + websites)!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url) as URLRequest)
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    }


    //MARK:- WKNavigationDelegate

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Strat to load")
    }
    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("finish to load")
    }

}
```

Here is the snippet which I want to add:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:selfselector:@selector(updateWeb) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)updateWeb
{
    [webView reload];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can put the scheduler code in ViewDidLoad Method. It will call updateWeb method after N seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSTimer to call the method every 5 seconds and use -reload method of UIWebview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://" + websites)!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url) as URLRequest)
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


@objc func update() {
     webView.reload()
}
```

Comment: After adding the snippet in above mentioned way, I am getting this error: Ambiguous reference to member 'webView'

Comment: @IAmAndroid I Updated my answer, noe try again.

Comment: @IAmAndroid, did you created webView programatically or added in storyboard?

Comment: @IAmAndroid, Okay, Thats great.

Comment: How do I enter the values programmatically in to the text box in the same webpage which is opened in the WebView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163989/discussion-between-iamandroid-and-kuldeep).

Comment: @IAmAndroid, you want to programatically add text in textBox which is open in WebView?

Comment: Yes, a predefined value to fill in the textbox.